# Operate and speed control a 230V 50Hz AC Ceiling Fan with Power MOSFET based Dimmer Circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ac, fan, dimmer

I am trying to control the speed of ceiling fan at my home using a power MOSFET based dimmer circuit.
The ceiling fan operates at 230V AC and can consume maximum 50 to 75 Watts power.

The circuit which I am using to control the speed of this fan is shown in below image. Some important highlights of the circuit are:

- The Fan is connected between Load+ and Load- terminals
- Live is 230V AC, IRF740A is Power MOSFET and PC817 is optical isolator
- PWM control signal is provided at the input of optical isolator via a microcontroller

[image: Power MOSFET based Dimmer circuit]

Here is what I observe when I try to operate the ceiling fan using above circuit:

1. When I increase the duty cycle of PWM, it successfully increases fan speed accordingly
2. When I decrease the PWM duty cycle slowly, fan still runs at same speed, and doesn't slow down
3. When I turn off the PWM, fan stops with a sudden jerk, and my MOSFET blows off after becoming too hot
4. The same circuit works well for dimming of resistive loads like incandescent bulb

So I wanted to know, what modifications do I need to make in my circuit, to safely handle the decrease in fan speed?

I want to make sure that after operating the fan at 100%, even if I turn off the PWM suddenly, the fan should still stop gradually and not with a jerk.